# Как сделать RecyclerView с изменяемым свойством ячеек?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-ui

То есть задача следующая, у меня есть набор каталогов с объектами. Я хочу отображать это как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где большая ячейка это название каталога, а маленькие - это собственно название объектов. 
Как я понимаю при создании RecyclerView необходимо указывать GridLayoutManager. Вопрос как динамически менять число столбцов в адаптере  для различных холдеров?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете типы элементов (`getItemViewType` в адаптере), а именно так и надо поступать, тогда:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
            case TYPE_CATEGORY:
                return 3;
            case TYPE_OBJECT:
                return 1;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Ну либо аналогично через список объектов, который вы выводите:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if(mItems.get(position).isCategory())
            return 3;
        else
            return 1;
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!